# The spring autowire dependcy fails for AWS Lambda funciton

Tags: java, spring, lambda, dependency-injection

The Autowire dependency failed when invoking lambda function throws NullPointerException

```
@ComponentScan("com.cashe")
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    @Autowired
    ElectronicPaymentReconciliationServiceImpl service;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(ReconApplication.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load spring boot application", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest input, Context context) {
        System.out.println("application started");
        service.processEelectronicRePaymentReconciliation();
        return handler.proxy(input, context);
    }
}
```

Lambda invoke :com.check.LambdaHandler::handleRequest
I have tried using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext this fails for other classes with autowire.
ALso used @ImportResource(locations = { "classpath:beans/factorybean-spring-ctx.xml" }) where i defined bean in xml.
the application works fine when its started as spring boot.
but once invoke as lambda function the Autowiring does not happen, how to inject dependency just like spring boot?
If I'm directly inject dependency at constructor and starting the SessionFactory is being **deinitialized**.

Comment: The main point of Spring is to avoid static configuration, so this code looks a a bit suspect, it should be possible to make the lambda handler a non-static Spring bean. 
My guess is you are using Spring boot, and that there is some autoconfiguration, so please post a github project, that all us to troubleshoot.